# I want to combine the databases from two different sites under one URL. How is this possible?

Tags: database

I have a small site that I want to merge with a bigger one. Both on Wordpress.  How can I merge the second one with the first?

I know that one solution would be to make the smaller one a subdomain of the bigger one, but I would like the following thing to happen: when I click on a category or a tag, posts from both sites/databases would appear. Something like Smashing Magazine did when it assimilated designinformer.com.

The other solution and the one that I would prefer would be to merge the two databases, but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the software you're using to run the sites, which you haven't specified. If you wrote your own code from scratch, the answer would be "OK, so just do it." (and you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place). If you're using code written by someone else, the answer then depends on whether that code supports such a feature out of the box, or whether you know enough to modify it to do that.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. The sites are both on Wordpress, it's not something that I built from scratch

Comment: OK, fair enough. If you edit that into your question, I can take back my downvote. Do note that there's also [a specific Stack Exchange site for Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com); you might try re-asking your question over there if you don't get any good answers here.

Answer (score 1):

> when I click on a category or a tag, posts from both sites/databases would appear

The easiest thing to do would be to export the content from Site 2 - the built-in exporter should be good enough for this - and then import it into Site 1.  That should bring in the content without too many overall issues.

The things you will need to be careful about are:

- Permalinks.  Make sure both sites are using the same permalink pattern before merging.
- Categories/Tags.  To be safe, make sure Site 1 and Site 2 have the same taxonomies
- Broken links.  Some internal links on the Site 2 content will most likely break during import.  You will need to run a search and replace on the database and replace all instances of site2.com with site1.com
- Custom Functionality. If Site 2 has Custom Post Types or content is otherwise dependent on a plugin or custom functions, make sure those are replicated on Site before the import.

I strongly suggest creating a test version of Site 1 (if you don't have one already) and running a test import :)